# end previous animation if next started

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have animations like this

```
<hhtml>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$().ready(function(){

   $(".btn").click(function(){
var obj=$(this).parent().find("img");
var h=$(obj).height();
var w=$(obj).width();
var st=$(obj).offset().top;
var sl=$(obj).offset().left;    

$("body").append("<div id='mtc' style='position:absolute;z-index:100;top:"+st+"px;left:"+sl+"px;'></div>");

$(obj).clone().appendTo("#mtc");
$("#mtc").css({height:'100px',width:'100px',opacity: '0.8'});

$("#mtc").animate({ 
       left:"999px",
       top:"0px"
        },2000,function(){
            $(this).remove();
            });


     });

});
</script>
<style>
   div{
     width:200px;
     height:300px;
     margin:10px;
     padding:5px;
     float:left;
   }
   p{
      .....
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div> <h3>img1</h3> <img src='a.png'>  <p class='btn'>Click</p> </div>
  <div> <h3>img1</h3> <img src='a.png'>  <p class='btn'>Click</p> </div>
  <div> <h3>img1</h3> <img src='a.png'>  <p class='btn'>Click</p> </div>
  <div> <h3>img1</h3> <img src='a.png'>  <p class='btn'>Click</p> </div>
  <div> <h3>img1</h3> <img src='a.png'>  <p class='btn'>Click</p> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

it works fine, but when 1 animation is in progress and i click another .btn to start another.
as 2nd animation starts then both are stoped (and hangs for a while).
**i need to make them smooth.**

Comment: http://jsbin.com/iluyux/2/edit where's the issue ?

Comment: There's an extra "h" in your html, and what exactly is supposed to be ready, usually it's the document, and not just an empty selector? You'll also need to position the elements before animating them, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/VdU6M/

Comment: Why are you wrapping your `obj` var in a dollar sign `$` when using it? Not necessary.